# How to paginate divs with ngx-pagination

Tags: angular, ngx-pagination

I'm new at angular so I have this issue.

```
<div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let student of students | paginate: {itemsPerPage:5, currentPage: p, totalItems: len}">
     {{student.name}}
</div>
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="p =$event"></pagination-controls>
```

I'm getting this error

> Cannot read property 'totalItems' of undefined
>       at PaginatePipe.push../node_modules/ngx-pagination/dist/ngx-pagination.js.PaginatePipe.transform

Component code:

```
public students= [];
public len;
ngOnInit() {
    this.serverService.getStudents().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.students= data,
        this.len = this.students.length
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: component code please?

Comment: and have you added `import {NgxPaginationModule} from 'ngx-pagination';`

Comment: students =[] is array that filled from api, and yes that is imported

Comment: I added totalItem: students.length, still not working

Comment: can you post the code of the component?

Comment: I have that in component ( Post is edited )

Comment: `p: number = 1;` add this

Comment: Good thought, but still the same problem. The problem I think is in that 'totalItem'

Comment: but as per the documentation you don't need to pass the same.

Comment: remove that totalItem option

Comment: in the documentation, totalItem is a must in dynamic arrays

Comment: I tried but is not working

Comment: can you show your `console.log(students)`

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e1f9hq?file=app%2Fapp.component.html it is working fine

Comment: I found this but its too complicated I don't understand 100%, I have differerent json result 
http://michaelbromley.github.io/ngx-pagination/#/server-paging

Comment: what you find complicated in that?

Answer (score 0):

```
<tbody *ngFor= "let item of con?.data?.countries | paginate:{itemsPerPage:10,currentPage: p}">
    <tr>
        <td>{{item['name']}}</td>
        <td>{{item['code']}}</td>                             
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Can you add some context to explain how this will answer the question, instead of code-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use `totalItems` as the pagination property here. `ngx-pagination` will automatically consider the length of the list/array as the total items.

```
<div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let student of students | paginate: {itemsPerPage:5, currentPage: p}">
     {{student.name}}
</div>
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="p =$event"></pagination-controls>
```

This will resolve your original issue/error:

> Cannot read property 'totalItems' of undefined at
> PaginatePipe.push../node_modules/ngx-pagination/dist/ngx-pagination.js.PaginatePipe.transform

Answer (score -1):

```
I am working at Angular 8. This code is helpful to use the 
pagination. I declare base url in API_URL in environment.ts.
example: API_URL:"http....",
endpoint: country

HTML code:
<tbody *ngFor= "let item of con?.data?.countries 
|paginate:itemsPerPage:10,currentPage: p}">
<tr>
<td>{{item['name']}}</td>
<td>{{item['code']}}</td>                             
</tr>
</tbody>
```

example.component.ts:

con:any;

```
ngOnInit() {
this.http.get(`${environment.API_URL}/country`).subscribe(res=>{
this.con=res      
})
}
```

Comment: import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination';

Comment: npm install ngx-pagination --save

Comment: Why did you add more code in the comments? Just edit your question

Comment: Just because what should install and what should import